# Отсутствие в git изменений, внесенных вручную на удаленный сервер

Tags: git

Суть такова:
Существует два сервера - боевой и дев. На дев существуют две ветки git - dev и master. Соответственно логика работы такая: разработчики пушат в дев - делается сборка на деве - всё ок - master мерджится с dev - dev мерджится с master - делается сборка на боевом из master. 
Но тут возникла проблема. Видимо, кто-то вносил изменения напрямую в файл на удаленном сервере через консоль (да, ай-яй-яй, доступы есть напрямую) и при мердже MASTER с DEV эти, сделанные вручную, изменения не появились в DEV ветке, однако при переключении на master, изменения есть, хотя коммитов с ним не было.

Вопрос такой: может кто-нибудь объяснить природу явления? По моим джунским меркам кажется, будто мастер хранит готовый "отпечаток" сборки со внесенными изменениями, но самих изменений не видит, отсюда и мерджить из master в dev ему нечего.

Comment: Если есть изменения и нет коммитов, может стоит их закоммитить и попробовать смерджить?

Comment: Если сливаете "dirty" ветку (там где есть любые изменения в рабочем каталоге: неотслеживаемые, либо отслеживаемые в индексе) с другой, мерж пройдет успешно (или с конфликтами). Но "те самые" изменения так и останутся изменениями, их в коммите, не будет. Вам нужно понять, что есть репозиторий, есть рабочий каталог этого репозитория. И есть репозитории без рабочего каталога (bare-репозитории).